# Beginner making a console app game, having a problem with property inheritance

Tags: c#, console-application

In my input class I have a switch statement that filters through all the possible input commands. One of them is 'Heal', and I would like it to display all the heal items the player has, and ask them to choose one to use. However, when I reach the point where the player healed by the amount the given healItem can, the healItem has no definition for 'AmountToHeal'. I have a class called Item, and HealItem is a derived class. Only the properties of Item are given when I type 'playerHealth += healItem.'.

```
case "Heal":
                if (player.Inventory.OfType<HealItem>().Any())
                {
                    foreach (var item in player.Inventory)
                    {
                        if (item.GetType() == typeof(HealItem))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("You have " + item.Name);
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Which heal item would you like to use? Enter heal item name:");
                    var healItemInput = Console.ReadLine();
                    foreach (var item in player.Inventory)
                    {
                        if (item.GetType() == typeof(HealItem) && healItemInput == item.Name)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
```

In that final if() is where I need to replenish the player's health based on the healItem's healAmount.

Item class:

```
 public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }



}
```

HealItem Class:

```
    public class HealItem : Item
{
    public int HealAmount { get; set; }

    public HealItem(string name, string description, int healAmount)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;
        this.HealAmount = healAmount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I completely understand your question, but I realised you said, "Only the properties of Item are given when I type 'playerHealth += healItem.'". Taking the question as, "why aren't HealItem properties being shown", have you tried making an explicit cast to HealItem?

the code will look something like this:

```
playerHealth += ((HealItem)item).HealAmount
```

for more readability, you can write:

```
HealItem healItem = item
playerHealth += healItem.HealAmount
```

using the HealItem instead of var should explicitly cast it to a HealItem type.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! I made a temporary list of type HealItem, and iterated through that for the heal item selection. Worked flawlessly.